# AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer issues with Video Gravity and Face Detection Accuracy

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avcapturesession, face-recognition, cifacefeature

I want to use AVFoundation to set up my own camera feed and process the live feed to detect smiles.

A lot of what I need has been done here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/SquareCam/Introduction/Intro.html

This code was written a long time back, so I needed to make some modifications to use it the way I want to in terms of appearance.

The changes I made are as follows:

- I enabled auto layout and size classes so as I wanted to support different screen sizes. I also changed the dimensions of the preview layer to be the full screen.
- The session Preset is set to AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto for iPhone and iPad
- Finally, I set the video gravity to AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill (this seems to be the keypoint)

Now when I run the application, the faces get detected but there seems to be an error in the coordinates of where the rectangles are drawn

[image: seems like the y is a bit off here in landscape]

[image: seems like the x is a bit off in portrait]

When I change the video gravity to AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspect, everything seems to work fine again.

[image: face gets captured, both actually do, just bad timing for the screenshot]

[image: in portrait as well]

The only problem is then, the camera preview is not the desired size which is the full screen.

So now I am wondering why does this happen. I notice a function in square cam: videoPreviewBoxForGravity which processes the gravity type and seems to make adjustments. 
- (CGRect)videoPreviewBoxForGravity:(NSString *)gravity frameSize:(CGSize)frameSize apertureSize:(CGSize)apertureSize

One thing I noticed here, the frame size stays the same regardless of gravity type.

Finally I read somewhere else, when setting the gravity to AspectFill, some part of the feed gets cropped which is understandable, similar to ImageView's scaletoFill.

My question is, how can I make the right adjustments to make this app work for any VideoGravity type and any size of previewlayer.

I have had a look at some related questions, for example [CIDetector give wrong position on facial features](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16549410/cidetector-give-wrong-position-on-facial-features) seems to have a similar issue but it does not help

Thanks, in advance.